# laravel Insert a query result in a join of another query builder

Tags: laravel

this current nested query do not perform the join with the obj passed in the join of the second query ($visit), what is the best way to perform that?

```
   $obj=obj::with('address','location','activity')->get();
   $visit=Visit::with('opening','place')->join($obj,'visit.id_obj','=','obj.id')
   ->get();
```

this is the error

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the join in second query?

Comment: I would to obtain only the obj of the previous query , that are in the table visit

Comment: I am not sure if i understood but you could do something like:
$obj=obj::with('address','location','activity')->get();
$visit=Visit::with('opening','place')->whereIn('id_obj', $obj->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
This will fetch you collection of visits whose obj_id exists in previous collection.

Comment: Thanks, but this approach not finds the match

Comment: Tell me exactly ur use case, I will try to help.

Comment: I aspect only the obj that have a visit. For this reason you can see the join 'visit.id_obj','=','obj.id'